# EXC BAD Access RestKit

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, restkit

```
    In ClassA.h
    @interface ClassA : NSObject<RKObjectLoaderDelegate,RKRequestDelegate>
    @property(nonatomic,strong)NSMutableDictionary *inputDict;

     ClassA.m
//After Implementation
      @synthesize inputDict;

        -(void)sendRequestWithInputDict:(NSMutableDictionary*)inputDictVal
        {
        RKURL *baseURL = [RKURL URLWithBaseURLString:baseUrl];
           RKObjectManager * manager = [RKObjectManager objectManagerWithBaseURL:baseURL];  
            [manager setClient:[RKClient sharedClient]];


            manager.client.requestQueue.showsNetworkActivityIndicatorWhenBusy = YES;
            RKObjectLoader *objectLoader = [manager loaderWithResourcePath:@"/getLocation"];  
            objectLoader.serializationMIMEType = RKMIMETypeJSON;
            objectLoader.method = RKRequestMethodPOST;
            objectLoader.params = inputDictVal;
            objectLoader.delegate = self;
            [objectLoader send];
        }

     -(void)getLocation
   {
      inputDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
     [self sendRequest:inputDict];
   }
```

baseUrl is declared in constant file which i am importing here.
I am trying to call a sendRequest Function from another class. But i get a EX_BAD_ACCESS in requestWillPrepareForSend(RKRequest.m).

i think some object is released automatically. i don't know which one is...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using Blocks i can able to send request to the server and getting response from it.  i found the nice tutorial here http://kalapun.com/blog/2012/05/17/how-i-restkit/

```
-(void)sendRequest:(NSMutableDictionary*)inputDict withResourcePath:(NSString*)resourcePath
{
     RKURL *baseURL = [RKURL URLWithBaseURLString:baseUrl];
        RKObjectManager *manager = [RKObjectManager objectManagerWithBaseURL:baseURL];  
        [manager setClient:[RKClient sharedClient]];


        [manager loadObjectsAtResourcePath:resourcePath usingBlock:^(RKObjectLoader *objectLoader){


        objectLoader.method = RKRequestMethodPOST;
        objectLoader.params = inputDict;

        objectLoader.onDidFailWithError = ^(NSError *error){

        NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);

        };
        objectLoader.onDidLoadResponse = ^(RKResponse *response) {
            NSLog(@"response: %@", [response bodyAsString]);
        };


    }];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the instance variables `baseUrl` and `inputDict`. **Always** use properties instead of instance variables and you will never face such problems.

Comment: graver-Thanks for your response. i have updated my code. This is my real scenario. Please check it.

Comment: In which line does it crashes?

Comment: in objectLoader.delegate = self;

Comment: It(EXC_BAD_ACCESS) points to requestWillPrepareForSend in RKRequest.m

Comment: When i set a property for my own class(classA ) and assign it's instance to delegate(classA *obj; objectLoader.delegate = obj; ). crashes gone. but the delegate methods are not calling.

Comment: the pblm was, i am using local variable to call a function sendRequest, instead of using @property(nonatomic,strong)

Answer (score 0):

There are many things that are wrong with your code. The most obvious is not retaining the object manager (unless this becomes the sharedManager) another is trying to load an object but using POST. Although, judging by the errors you report, I think your ClassA instance is being dealloced, and because it is set as a delegate you are getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS. I suggest you move to using the block based methods and not the delegate callbacks.

Comment: i am now using blocks for sending Request, it works fine now. i will post it as an answer. May be it will help for someone.